# How do I store the value given from a function back into the main function without using a global variable

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to write a function that checks if the user input is within the appropriate range.

When you enter a value outside the range, then a number that is within it, the value that is within the range doesn't replace the number outside of it. (not sure if that makes sense but oh well)

The easiest solution is to use a global variable, but that is considered a "bad coding habit"

What should I do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int NUM_GAMES = 2;
int getValidScore(int num);
int getValidGame(int num);
void changeScore(int scores[NUM_GAMES]);


int main()
{
    int scores[NUM_GAMES] = {14,36};
    cout << scores[0] << endl << scores[1] << endl;
    changeScore(scores);
    cout << scores[0] << endl << scores[1];
    return 0;
}



int getValidScore(int num)
{
    if(num>50||num<0)
    {
        do {
            cout << "Choose a valid score (0-50)\n";
            cin >> num;
        }while(num>50||num<0);
    }
}

int getValidGame(int num)
{
    if(num>=3||num<=0)
    {
        do {
            cout << "Choose a valid game number\n";
            cin >> num;
        }while(num>4||num<0);
    }
}

void changeScore(int scores[NUM_GAMES])
{
    int game,score;
    cout << "Enter in the game number\n";
    cin >> game;
    getValidGame(game);
    cout << "Please enter in a score";
    cin >> score;
    getValidScore(score);
    scores[game-1]=score;
}
```

For example, I want to change the first number from 14 to 32. I enter 64 first, then 32. 64 is then shown instead of 32. If you do that with the game number, it won't replace any number since the array isn't that big.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Which function isn't doing what you want?

Comment: I want to change the second number in the array in the getValidScore to 32, but if I enter 64 before it (or any number above 50) that number gets stored instead of 32

Comment: Short answer, you either return the value and assign back in `main()` or you pass a reference and update the reference within the function so the change is available back in the caller -- or (not recommended) as in C, you pass a pointer as a parameter and update the value at that address within the function with the same result as the reference. In your case you must validate that `game` after `cin >> game;` has the value of either `1` or `2`.

Comment: And how would you do the first option David?

Comment: You are using a Plain Old Array -- which is fine, and you can pass it as shown, but ideally you can simply pass a pointer `void changeScore(int *scores)`. After `if (cin >> game && game > 0 && game <= NUM_GAMES) { /* then read and VALIDATE score */ scores[game] = score; }` which will update the element of `scores` and that change will be seen in the caller (`main()` here)

Comment: Thanks, I think I figured out what you are trying to say

Comment: Note your limits in `getValidGame(int num)` of  `while(num>4||num<0);` does NOT limits the value of `game` to `1` or `2` so any value of `0` or `3` will result in *Undefined Behavior* causing `scores[game-1]=score;` to attempt to set element index `-1` or `2` of any array whose valid indexes are `0` and `1`.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to change that one to 3 for this example. The 0-4 was in the original code that I pulled this from.

Comment: I also would not mix indexes with game numbers. It's best to just change your range match your indexes, e.g. `"Enter in the game number (0-1): "`. If you must adjust, then adjust at the point of input, e.g. for `game` if entering `1-2`, you would `cin >> num; num -= 1;` The rest of your code then uses index-only for consistency. (less chance of forgetting to add or subtract `1` somewhere else)

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear whether you have solved you problem or not. In your code above you have a number of problems that can be boiled down to three categories (all are related):

1. failure to validate any of the user inputs,
2. failure of your input logic, and
3. failure to choose an appropriate return-type for your input function so you can determine whether the input succeeded or failed.

When taking user input you **must** validate the stream-state following each input to determine whether the input succeeded or failed. The stream-state is represented by a number of state bits described at [std::basic_ios::rdstate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdstate), those being `goodbit`, `badbit`, `failbit` and `eofbit`. You are provided with convenient member functions with which to check the bits, `.good()`, `.bad()`, `.fail()`, and `.eof()`. [std::basic_ios](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios) The two that are unrecoverable are `.bad()` and `.eof()` while `.fail()` indicates a matching failure such as entering `"two"` where an integer `2` was expected. There you can clear the `failbit` by using the `.clear()` member function and then remove the offending characters from the input-stream with `.ignore()`.

When implementing your logic to check the state, you first need to know if any failure occurred, e.g.:

```
bool getValidScore (int& num)
{
    do {
        std::cout << "\nPlease enter in a score: ";
        
        if (!(std::cin >> num)) {                       /* validate EVERY input */
```

(**note:** return-type change to `bool`)

If `std::cin >> num` fails, then you know a bit is set in the stream state. You now need to systematically check which bit is set to know if the error is recoverable or non-recoverable, you check for non-recoverable errors first, e.g.

```
            if (std::cin.eof() || std::cin.bad()) {     /* check state, eof or bad */
                std::cerr << "  error: unrecoverable stream error.\n";
                return false;
            }
```

(**note:** return of `false` indicates to the calling function that the user-input failed)

Now you check whether a recoverable error (matching failure) occurred:

```
            else if (std::cin.fail()) {                 /* check matching failure */
                std::cerr << "  error: invalid integer input.\n";
                std::cin.clear();   /* clear stream state and ignore offending chars */
                std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }
```

Now you can check any specific range limits you have in your code. For instance `MAX_SCORE` is `50` given your description. You would check as:

```
        else if (num < 0 || MAX_SCORE < num)            /* check value in range */
            std::cerr << "  error: out of range - score (0-50)\n";
```

Finally, and only after your user-input passes ALL validations, do you consider it valid input ready to use, e.g.

```
        else            /* when all satisfied, break loop */
            break;
    
    } while (true);
    
    return true;
}
```

(**note:** those pieces can be put together to form your complete `bool getValidScore(int& num);` function)

You would write a near identical `bool getValidGame(int& num);` function where the only difference would be (1) the prompt to output to the user; and (2) the range used to validate a good input. Instead of duplicating the code, why not pass the `prompt` and `min` and `max` as parameters and use a single function? That way you have one function to use to get any integer value you need within a range.

```
bool getIntRange (int& num, std::string prompt, int min, int max)
{
    do {
        std::cout << '\n' << prompt;
        
        if (!(std::cin >> num)) {                       /* validate EVERY input */
            if (std::cin.eof() || std::cin.bad()) {     /* check state, eof or bad */
                std::cerr << "  error: unrecoverable stream error.\n";
                return false;
            }
            else if (std::cin.fail()) {                 /* check matching failure */
                std::cerr << "  error: invalid integer input.\n";
                std::cin.clear();   /* clear stream state and ignore offending chars */
                std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }
        }
        else if (num < min || max < num)                /* check value in range */
            std::cerr << "  error: out of range - allowed (" 
                        << min << "-" << max << ")\n";
        else            /* when all satisfied, break loop */
            break;
    
    } while (true);
    
    return true;
}
```

(**note:** you can add a check of `if (prompt.len() > 0)` to control the prompt allowing you to pass an empty string if no prompt is desired)

Now that your user-input functions return to the caller information about whether input succeeded or failed, you are ready to use that to validate the both inputs to determine if the `scores` array can be updated, e.g.

```
bool changeScore (int *scores)
{
    int game = 0, score = 0;
    
    /* you must validate both inputs */
    if (!getIntRange(game, "Please enter in a game: ", 0, NUM_GAMES-1)) {
        std::cerr << "getValidGame(game) - failed.\n";
        return false;
    }
    
    if (!getIntRange(score, "Please enter in a score: ", 0, MAX_SCORE)) {
        std::cerr << "getValidScore(score) - failed.\n";
        return false;
    }
    
    scores[game]=score;     /* only update if both inputs were valid */
    
    return true;
}
```

(**note:** the change of return-type to `bool` so you can communicate any failure of any one user-input back to the caller from this function as well)

In fact, the only functions you want to type as `void` will be functions without any consequences such as functions where you simply print information (and certain classes of callback functions, but not as prevalent in C++ as in C). By returning `bool` from `changeScore()` you can now determine whether or not you need to display any updated values of the scores from main, e.g.

```
int main(void)
{
    int scores[] = {14,36};
    
    std::cout << "\nOriginal: ";
    prnScores (scores);
    
    if (changeScore (scores)) {
        std::cout << "\nUpdated : ";
        prnScores (scores);
    }
}
```

For completeness, you are not using anything from the `<iomanip>` header, but your do need to include the `<limits>` header, as well as another constant for `MAX_SCORE`. That you can do as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>       /* for limits associated with std::numeric_limits */

const int NUM_GAMES = 2,        /* if you need a constant, declare one (or more) */
          MAX_SCORE = 50;
```

The `prnScores()` function references from `main()` can simply be:

```
/* simple print scores function */
void prnScores (int *scores)
{
    std::cout << "scores:";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_GAMES; i++)
        std::cout << " " << scores[i];
    
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Now if you put that altogether, you can handle inputs and errors gracefully. The only improvement you would want to make is read the user inputs with `getline()` into a `std::string` and then use a `std::stringstream` to extract the values. This lets you handle more gracefully circumstances where you get valid input, but the user adds stray characters afterwards. (that is still handled correctly above, though you may see an extra prompt generated as the extra characters are processed).

**Example Use/Output**

For example, intentionally providing invalid input, your code would now complete successfully when the user ultimately entered correct input:

```
$ ./bin/chgelement

Original: scores: 14 36

Please enter in a game: two
  error: invalid integer input.

Please enter in a game: -1
  error: out of range - allowed (0-1)

Please enter in a game: 1

Please enter in a score: thirty-two
  error: invalid integer input.

Please enter in a score: 51
  error: out of range - allowed (0-50)

Please enter in a score: 32

Updated : scores: 14 32
```

Also note I have used the array indexes for the range throughout the code. If you need to shift by one so the games choice is `1-2` then handle that at the point of input so your code remains consistent in all other places using the actual indexes (much less chance of an off-by-one somewhere else)

Look thing over and let me know if you have further questions.