# How can I make my loop ask me for my next input in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a Yahtzee game told hold my dice. But I keep getting an infinite loop.

```
cout << "Choose what Dice you want to hold. Use numbers from 0-4. If you are done selecting Dice type 5. ";
    cin >> Hold;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        switch (Hold)
        {
        case 0: cout << "You held the " << NumArray[0] << " Die. ";
            continue;
        case 1: cout << "You held the " << NumArray[1] << " Die. ";
            continue;
        case 2: cout << "You held the " << NumArray[2] << " Die. ";
            continue;
        case 3: cout << "You held the " << NumArray[3] << " Die. ";
            continue;
        case 4: cout << "You held the " << NumArray[4] << " Die. ";
            continue;
        case 5: i + 4;
            continue;
        }
        i++;
    }
```

I have tried using a for loop and a while loop. I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this. Or I'm just blind and doing something that is simple. I'm still new to C++.

Comment: Input validation and checking the stream-state is mandatory. A [recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64423230/3422102) may help.

Comment: Move `cin >> Hold;` to inside the `for` loop else it is only executed once. And `i + 4` does nothing. Did you mean `i += 4`? Lastly, there is no need for `switch`, just use the input value `NumArray[Hold]`

Comment: Discuss what you want `case 5: i + 4;` to do with [your Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you've posted I would say you to do this:

```cpp
    cout << "Choose what Dice you want to hold. Use numbers from 0-4. If you are done selecting Dice type 5. ";
    do
    {
        cin >> Hold;
        switch (Hold)
        {
        case 0:
            cout << "You held the " << NumArray[0] << " Die. ";
            break;
        case 1:
            cout << "You held the " << NumArray[1] << " Die. ";
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "You held the " << NumArray[2] << " Die. ";
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "You held the " << NumArray[3] << " Die. ";
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "You held the " << NumArray[4] << " Die. ";
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    } while(Hold != 5);
```

Or better:

```cpp
    cout << "Choose what Dice you want to hold. Use numbers from 0-4. If you are done selecting Dice type 5. ";
    do
    {
        cin >> Hold;
        if(Hold >= 0 && Hold <= 4
            cout << "You held the " << NumArray[Hold] << " Die. ";
    } while(Hold != 5);
```

However, if it's a game I suppose you should save the input data somewhere to use it later. I think you could do this:

```cpp
    bool heldDies[5] = {false};
    cout << "Choose what Dice you want to hold. Use numbers from 0-4. If you are done selecting Dice type 5. ";
    do
    {
        cin >> Hold;
        if(Hold >= 0 && Hold <= 4
        {
            heldDies[Hold] = !heldDies[Hold];
            cout << heldDies[Hold] ? "You held the ":"You dropped the " << NumArray[Hold] << " Die. ";
        }
    } while(Hold != 5);
```

Then you would have the `heldDies` array to use it later.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand what you actually meant, but I think it could be as simple as that:

```
cout << "Choose what Dice you want to hold. Use numbers from 0-4. If you are done selecting Dice type 5. ";

vector<int> HeldIndices;

while(true)
{
   cin >> Hold;
   if (Hold == 5) break;
   HeldIndices.push_back(Hold)
}

// the next will print all the recorded dice like:
// "You held the 4 5 6 Dice."
if (HeldIndices.size() > 0) 
{
  cout << "You held the ";
  for (auto& HeldIndex : HeldIndices) 
  {
     cout << NumArray[HeldIndex] << ' ';
  }
  cout << " Dice." << endl;
}
else
{
  cout << "You held no dice";
}
```

The `vector<int>` is like an array, but it has dynamic size and it's easier to work with.